# How to convert a homogeneous fusion::vector to an (std/boost)::array

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I am relatively new to boost, so I believe this is an easy problem:
Given, say a `fusion::vector<int, int, int>`, I need a good way to turn it into an `array<int, 3>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the builtin adaption of `array<>` (std or boost) and `copy`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3481e69474467ff2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/boost_array.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using namespace boost;

int main() {
    fusion::vector<int, int, int> fv(1,2,3);
    array<int, 3> arr;

    fusion::copy(fv, arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @sehe's answer you can also use `fusion::invoke` to get rid of the uninitialized array.

```cpp
#include <boost/fusion/functional/invocation/invoke.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/boost_array.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

using namespace boost;

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    fusion::vector<int, int, int> fv(1,2,3);

    auto arr = fusion::invoke([](int x, int y, int z){return array<int, 3>{x, y, z};}, fv);

    for(auto i : arr)
        std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

which becomes more attractive in C++14

```
    auto arr = fusion::invoke([](auto... xs){return array<int, 3>{xs...};}, fv);
```

and in C++17

```
    auto arr = fusion::invoke([](auto... xs){return std::array{xs...};}, fv);
```